# Android button text alignment issue

Tags: android, android-layout

Consider the following XML and the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textSize="100sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textSize="100sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

There is enough space for the button at the top to position the text at the middle, but still some portion (at the bottom) is trimmed, why?

When I use the following background, still the text is not centered (see the output bellow)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
      <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:startColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
            <corners
                android:radius="0dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:bottom="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true" >
       <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:startColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
            <corners
                android:radius="0dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:bottom="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>        
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:startColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
            <corners
                android:radius="0dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:bottom="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

[image]

(Tested on emulator 10.1" WXGA 1280x800 screen, landscape)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it is the way how the View is rendered. The code of the button view applies a minimum top and bottom padding. Only if the height of the button is bigger than the height of the text + the default paddings the renderer starts to center the text vertically. It is like it is by natural design.

Comment: why do you rate this answer down, my answer is right, the other ones aren't

Comment: Probably because you don't give a proper solution to the problem. As far as I can see, you seem to be right, too. That's a pity ;)

Answer (score 5):

That's probably a font padding. You can disable it by using `android:includeFontPadding=false` for that button.

Comment: I tested this, but, I can't see any different by using android:includeFontPadding=false.

Comment: Then, that means, that the 9-patch for the button background has defined area for content and some of it's space is reserved for margins. There is no "normal" way around it as far as I know. So you will have to create your own background for button for this to work. Not really a good idea, because your button is vanilla android and so it's different on different devices.

Comment: When I use my own background, still the button text is not centered. See my updated question.